Inconsistent ratings when drawing using Trueskill
I'm using Trueskill to try to create a rating system for a tennis tournament among my friends. Games are 1v1, so I'm trying out the following:
from trueskill import Rating, quality_1vs1, rate_1vs1
alice, bob = Rating(25), Rating(25)
print('#############')
print('No games')
print('#############')
print(alice)
print(bob)

alice, bob = rate_1vs1(alice, bob)
print('#############')
print('First game, winner alice')
print('#############')
print(alice)
print(bob)

alice, bob = rate_1vs1(bob, alice)
print('#############')
print('Second game, winner bob')
print('#############')
print(alice)
print(bob)

This outputs the following:
#############
No games
#############
trueskill.Rating(mu=25.000, sigma=8.333)
trueskill.Rating(mu=25.000, sigma=8.333)
#############
First game, winner alice
#############
trueskill.Rating(mu=29.396, sigma=7.171)
trueskill.Rating(mu=20.604, sigma=7.171)
#############
Second game, winner bob
#############
trueskill.Rating(mu=26.643, sigma=6.040)
trueskill.Rating(mu=23.357, sigma=6.040)

I would have expected both players having the same rating after these two games but I'll go with that, no issue. However, if I remove the second game and replace it with a draw and re-run the thing:
alice, bob = rate_1vs1(bob, alice, True)
print('#############')
print('Second game, draw')
print('#############')
print(alice)
print(bob)

I get the following:
#############
First game, winner alice
#############
trueskill.Rating(mu=29.396, sigma=7.171)
trueskill.Rating(mu=20.604, sigma=7.171)
#############
Second game, draw
#############
trueskill.Rating(mu=23.886, sigma=5.678)
trueskill.Rating(mu=26.114, sigma=5.678)

bob seems to have a better ranking when having drawn than when having won.
What's going on here? What am I doing wrong?

There is this part in the documentation: For example, 60% of matches in your game have finished as draw then you should set draw_probability to 0.60:
env = TrueSkill(draw_probability=0.60) Different games should have set that variable accordingly

@Zibelas can you point to that part in the documentation? I haven't been able to find it.

I currently don't understand fully what you meant. I should calculate myself how many draws I have (this will be changing as the tournament goes on) and tell TrueSkill?

Im just quoting their documentation; from what I understand is that the draw value should be customized according to the type of games you are playing. If you compare a game like soccer to a game of tennis, a draw is more common in soccer. Im not actually sure how you would draw in tennis .

Thanks. However even considering that, I still don't understand how a draw can be taken as
a) more valuable to a player and
b) more significant (sigma is also decreasing more
than with a victory

If you read further, they say this about a draw: However, empirical findings in the game of chess show that draws are more likely between professional players than beginners. Hence, chance of drawing also seems to depend on the skill level. Hence, the chance of drawing only depends on the difference of the two player’s playing strength.
